# PHP: Show value of foreach loop in another foreach loop with corresponding index

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

this is how my XML document looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <result name="response" numFound="111" start="0">
    <doc>
      <str name="id">http://www.ams.at/</str>
      <str name="title">Startseite - Arbeitsmarktservice Österreich</str>
      <str name="url">http://www.ams.at/</str>
      <str name="content">evölkerung zurück. 982.000 Personen ab 50 Jahren hatten zuletzt einen</str>
    </doc>
    <doc>
      <str name="id">http://www.ams.at/ueber-ams/medien/download-formulare</str>
      <str name="title">Download und Formulare - Arbeitsmarktservice Österreich</str>
      <str name="url">http://www.ams.at/ueber-ams/medien/download-formulare</str>
      <str name="content">Download und Formulare - Arbeitsmarktnen Kundmachung AMS-Richtlinien Impressum AGB Sitemap Die</str>
    </doc>
  </result>
  <lst name="highlighting">
    <lst name="http://www.ams.at/service-arbeitsuchende/download-formulare">
      <arr name="content">
        <str>Service für Arbeitsuchende Service für Unternehmen <em>Berufsinformation</em> & Weiterbildung Service für Partner</str>
      </arr>
    </lst>
    <lst name="http://www.ams.at/berufsinfo-weiterbildung/berufsinfo-broschueren">
      <arr name="content">
        <str><em>Berufsinformation</em>: Kataloge, Broschüren und mehr - Arbeitsmarktservice Österreich English Schrift</str>
      </arr>
    </lst>
  </lst>
</response>
```

The purpose is to display the search results of a `Solr` query with `PHP`.
It displays `Title and the Content`.

I have a table where I do a `foreach` loop over the **doc** nodes where I get the `title`, `url` and `content`.

But I cant use the *content* field because I want only the relevant content of my search query. So I am using **Solr highlighting**. Unfortunately I have now the `$data->result->doc` data but the highlighting content is not in `result->doc`

What I need:
When I have my table and do a foreach loop to have an entry for each doc result, I want to have the corresponding content of the highlighting fields. `doc->title[0] + highlighting->content[0]` and so on.

Comment: is that xml or json?

Comment: Try to create a variable type array empty and push under what you need on the foreach loop :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(xml_file);
$i = 0;
foreach($xml->result->doc as $doc) {
  foreach ($doc->str as $str) {
    $name = $str->attributes()->name;
    echo $name . ': ' . $str . PHP_EOL;
  }
  $lstContent = $xml->xpath("/response/lst[@name='highlighting']")[0]->lst[$i]->arr->str;
  echo 'NEW CONTENT: ' . $lstContent . PHP_EOL;
  echo PHP_EOL;
  $i++;
}
```